# Return an array of values from one table column using mysql and PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am working on one small project, where I need to return an array of values from each row but only from one column (page) in the table.

My method looks like this:

```
public static function getMainArray() {
  $conn = parent::connect();
  $sql = "SELECT page FROM " . TBL_PAGES . " WHERE level = 0";

  try {
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    $pages = array();
    foreach ( $st->fetchAll() as $row ) {
      $pages[] = new Page( $row );
    }     
    parent::disconnect( $conn );
    return array( $pages);
  } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    parent::disconnect( $conn );
    die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
  }
}
```

When I print this array,

```
$pages = array();
$pages = Page::getMainArray();
print_r($pages);
```

output is following:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
  [0] => Page Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( 
    [id] => 
    [page] => home
    [url] => 
    [level] => 
    [parent] => 
    [nazov] => 
    [title_navi] => 
    [title_meta] => 
  ) 
)
  [1] => Page Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( 
    [id] => 
    [page] => about
    [url] => 
    [level] => 
    [parent] => 
    .
    .
    .
```

What do I need to change so output will be like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => home
  [1] => about
  [2] => orders
  [3] => info
  [4] => contact
)
```

Comment: `$pages` is already an array, why are you wrapping it with `array($pages)`?

Comment: why do you create an object Page?

Comment: SELECT page FROM ?? how you getting values from table other than page??

Comment: I have another method which takes care of it based on what page I'm on.<br> public static function getPageInfo( $page) $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TBL_PAGES . " WHERE page = :page";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what it have to be, without all the useless code

```
public static function getMainArray() {
  $conn = parent::getConnection();
  $sql = "SELECT page FROM " . TBL_PAGES . " WHERE level = 0";
  $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
  $st->execute();
  return $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}
```

note that `parent::getConnection()` method **should not** connect every time it is called, but always return already opened connection. `parent::disconnect()` should not be used here at all. As well as try..catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works just perfect. Well, I'm new to PDO and don't understand a lot of things. My connect() method return $conn so this should be fine, but I don't understand why I shouldn't be using disconnect() & try/catch. I can't remember what book or web forum it was, but I'm sure they mentioned to close connection at the end of method and to use try/catch. All for security reasons ...?

Comment: Most of books and - especially - forums are but piles of rubbish. Its authors have no idea what are they talking about but just reciting old mantras which they don't understand. In your code you are connecting as many times as many queries you runs, killing your server this way. You should connect only ONCE per application and use this connection all the way. All for sanity reasons.

Comment: Well, what is the best way to learn PDO? I'm sure books are crucial followed by many years of experience, but I haven't got a chance to work with experienced people. It makes sense to connect only once, so shall I use disconnect method once as well or I shouldn't use it at all? How dangerous is it to keep my connection open, because based on books it isn't secure at all and unfortunately this is everything I know. Thanks

Comment: As I told you before, whatever book told you that "it's insecure to keep connection open" is an utter, complete rubbish. A connection have to be opened once and then closed at the end of the script execution. Yet as PHP will do it automatically anyway - there is no point in doing it manually. As for the learning resource - start from the wiki under "PDO" tag here.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$pages[] = new Page( $row );
```

to

```
$pages[] = $row['page'];
```